# SQL query to select dates between two dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get date between two dates but i could not sort it out . Is it due my wrong date format or it is something other thing i am missing???

```
       SELECT * FROM (`employee`) WHERE `date` BETWEEN 2013-06-03 AND 2013-06-05
```

Comment: what is the datatype og the date column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used between statements before,

I think it should be;

```
SELECT * FROM (`employee`) WHERE `date` BETWEEN "2013-06-03" AND "2013-06-05"
```

with quotes, just a typo...

I personnally prefer;

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Date >= '03/06/2013' AND Date <= '05/06/2013'";
```

Comment: Do not use double quotes unless you are sure which SQL mode MySQL is using.

Answer (score 0):

I'll think comparing the unix timestamp of date should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM emloyee WHERE 
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP( date ) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-03') 
 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( date ) <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-06-05')
```

ref: [MYSQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (`employee`) WHERE `date` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2013-06-03','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2013-06-05','%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: How does `str_to_date` help?

Comment: Explicitly doing what MySQL will otherwise be doing implicitly anyway if it wants to use an index on a date type field.